# Error in jpeg(a_paste_function) : too many open devices

Tags: image, r

I am trying to output about 250 plots from an r-script and I'm receiving a "too many open devices" error. Is there some setting that I can adjust to avoid this problem?

Here is an example of how I am creating the plots:

```
for(x in 250) { 

plots <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x,y,lab=labels))
jpeg(a_paste_function)
print(plots)

}
```

One thing I notice is that when I `write.table`, the files are ready right away, whereas I always have to close R for the jpegs to be "printed". Perhaps that is the real problem, the method in which I'm dumping the plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dev.off() worked.

```
for(x in 250) { 

plots <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x,y,lab=labels))
jpeg(a_paste_function)
print(plots)
dev.off()
}
```